# How to fetch all data quickly from mongodb using indexing field without using limit

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, memory, indexing

I have around **~2 million** documents in my database, when i made an query in mongo for  which looks like:

```
db.collection.ensure_index("location")
db.collection.find({"location.name": {"$regex": 'norway', "$option": 'i'}}, {"_id:0", 'userid': 1, 'username': 1})
```

mongo document sample for location searching:

```
Mongodb document: {"location": {id:3235726, name: Oslo, Norway }}
```

In indexing i am not specified **cache_time** part, it uses default. Now, it shows me data after **2 or 4 seconds** which is very bad, and the most worse part when it doesn't find any location then it took around **25seconds** for searching operation. I mapped this time using python **time.time()** method. Then i put a **limit()** on query only for 100 documents, then it works a bit well. But what is the use case for me if i put a limit there, using **skip()** is very expansive while searching.

On other part if i am searching data using userid like, it doesn't contain regex type query:

```
db.collection.ensure_index("userid")
db.collection.find({"userid": 1213444}, {"_id:0", 'user_rank': 1, 'username': 1})
```

It works very efficiently, as id is integer and very fast. Only difference is i am using '**like**' query in location query part with regex, and i studied on mongo docs **regex** is not bad in terms of performance.

Should i go for increasing physical memory on my server which is currently 1.5G for using indexing efficiently or using **Apache Solr** search engine which index all my mongo docs through mongo_connector and sync data from mongodb to solr (Indexing data directly to solr is very expansive in terms of memory )?

I tried to put all efforts in my problem statement, if there is anything wrong with my problem statement then let me know, i can try my best to improve it.

Edit: Should i go for elasticsearch with mongo? because with index or without index search result is too slow, like maximum time it shows **260ms** which is too high

Comment: 1.5GB is a tiny amount of RAM.  But regardless of that, the answer below is correct, $regex is bad for performance, it's unlikely to read otherwise.

Comment: $regex is bad for /^a./, and /^a.$/ but using ^ anchor is better. My document looks like {location: {id:88, name: Delhi, India}} and i have to search data through country parameter this is the reason i am using regex, any alternative would be appreciate

Comment: You mean regex is *not* bad for /^abc... - left anchored case sensitive is good, anything else cannot use the index effectively.  The correct alternative is to store country as a separate field.

Comment: Also, the example you give, your "userid" is NOT an integer, '121344' is a *string* - that's what the quotes show.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: my mistake, by mistakenly i put there single quotes...its integer

Comment: And for all documents i have to fetch country parameter from location and update documents for new field? is it? but data is so huge

Comment: that's the price you have to pay: either your routine queries will be slow forever, or you can fix the schema (one time effort) and your queries will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

`$regex` does not always use index

> $regex can only use an index efficiently when the regular expression has an anchor for the beginning (i.e. ^) of a string and is a case-sensitive match. Additionally, while /^a/, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ match equivalent strings, they have different performance characteristics. All of these expressions use an index if an appropriate index exists; however, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ are slower. /^a/ can stop scanning after matching the prefix.

You have to create query to use index. You can check that index was used with [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) command

Comment: I already read this on mongo docs, location post from user is case-insensitive so i have to use option 'i' and without ^(anchor) it gives result a bit quick. I already mention an document example i have locations like {location :{id:888, name: india}}, and for index i already made an index on location and use in query...if there is something wrong then please mark it

Comment: @shihon just remove the index it will make your query too fast.
when you create a index on a field and apply regex search on that field mongo first matches regex in index and then again in collections it becomes double work for mongo thats why query is slow. Just remove index and you can see the difference. Hope it will help :)

Comment: @ShreyanceJain: I already did this thing, i Will try again and let you know the output..